# Google contact API with Oauth

Tags: java, api, google-contacts-api

I am new to Google Api have not used any of the API yet. Now I am doing a web application in java and I want to use Google Contact API V3 with OAUTH. I have followed the instruction on [this site](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). I am able to get the access_token but how to fetch value of access_token from URl. I tried [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) but not able to display contacts??

Where am I lacking.